# Why isnt my mongodb profile saving to database?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, save

The main issue is my code saves the first time around but then will not work no matter what I try. It should be simple to save to the database and it is the first time but after that the database refuses to save the data. I do not believe this is an issue of validation but rather something with the save method.

I am expecting the profile database to add another profile. However it only does this for the first profile added. After that it always produces some error. I have tried different post requests, i have tried deleting all elements in the database.

I am given the following error:

```
    Profile not created
    MongoServerError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: test.profiles index: email_1 dup key: { email: null }
    .../message_stream.js:33:9) at writeOrBuffer (internal/streams/writable.js:358:12) {
      index: 0,
      code: 11000,
      keyPattern: { email: 1 },
      keyValue: { email: null },
      [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(0) {}
    }
```

I am trying to save a profile to MongoDB database using mongoose with the following code:

```
    // create new profile
    router.post('/create', async (req, res) => {
    
        const profile = new Profile({
            user: {
                username: req.body.username,
                email: req.body.email,
                password: req.body.password1,
            },
            trips: [],
        });

        try {
            const prof1 = await profile.save();
            console.log(`created profile ${profile.user.username}`);
            console.log(req.params);
            return res.json(prof1);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log("Profile not created");
            console.log(err)
            return res.send(err);
        }
    });
```

Here is my profile Schema:

```
    const profileSchema = new Schema({
        user: {
            username: {
                type: String,
                required: [true, "Add a username"],
                unique: true,
            },
            email: {
                type: String,
                required: [true, "Add an email"],
                unique: true,
            },
            password: {
                type: String,
                required: [true, "Add a password"],
            },
        },
        trips: [{
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "Trip",
        }],
    }, {timestamps: true});
```

Comment: It seems that your code is not receiving the request data properly as the error mentions that the email value is null, check whether you are receiving the data properly and try again.

Comment: _"MongoServerError: E11000 duplicate key error ..."_  Mongoose created a unique index  on the MongoDB server based on your schema.  If you try to insert another document with an identical value for a unique index's key, the MongoDB server will refuse.  So perhaps you _want_ to allow identical values for `email` and therefore the schema should not have `unique: true` option for `email`?

Comment: I commented out the unique: true in the schema but the same issue is there. I am trying to send a post request using the REST Client VSCode extensions which works like Postman. However I get the same error every time. The only time I do not get the error is when I delete all profile entries and add a new profile. Only the first profile is saved fine and then after that I get the same error.

Comment: Did you delete/modify the index residing on the MongoDB server for that collection?

Comment: @rickhg12hs could you explain this? I checked mongodb and the cluster shows only one profile in the database?

Comment: @NicholasEby I don't know the exact instant `mongoose` creates an unique index.  I also don't know if/when it would drop/create or modify an index to make it non-unique.  You could look at all the indexes for that collection and see if they have a unique property.

Answer (score 2):

Your database already had a `Profile` with a `user.email` that is `null`. Since you have set that property to `unique` in your Schema then that's why you get the `E11000 duplicate key error`.

Now you're wondering why you have a `Profile` with a `user.email` that is `null`.  I suspect you have a problem with your form submission. Check to make sure the `name="email"` attribute is set on the `<input>` tag. If you are using postman to send the post request then check the spelling of the `email` property.

When you try to access it here:

```
email: req.body.email
```

The value is empty so `null` is being set.

Comment: This is my get request for all profiles in the database. There is only one object in the array. Also my form submission uses react and I do already have name="email"          
   [
  {
    "user": {
      "username": "james",
      "email": "james@gmail.com",
      "password": "james"
    },
    "_id": "64ff3e4b6cf82033856d420f",
    "trips": [],
  }
]

Comment: This part of the MongoServerError message `keyValue: { email: null },` tells you what the problematic value is, and its null. In your `router.post` do a `console.log(req.body.email)`  as the first statement to see what value is being passed to Express.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show enough of the data you're passing into the POST body but I'm assuming you resent the same request twice.

the constraints used in your `email` property are likely failing uniqueness.

If you pass an empty string for `email`, the next time you add it again will cause it to fail because the `email: ""` would not be unique.